# Cisco AnyConnect weird interaction with ethernet (DNS?)

Tags: windows, networking, cisco

We use [Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/security/anyconnect-secure-mobility-client/index.html) (Version 4.7.01076) at our company. Often in the morning after starting the AnyConnect client, I get a weird state with DNS on my setup. The most user visible effect (symptom) is the ping command:

[image]

The other less visible effects is that I cannot access the shared netword drives.

I eventually found a workaround, where I physically unplug the ethernet cable from the docking station (ThinkPad/Lenovo), wait for Wifi to connect, AnyConnect client would then reconnect over Wifi. At this point if I replug physically the ethernet cable, then everything is back in shape:

[image]

My very first issue is to properly define the issue (what is the actual bug?) I am having (in order to formulate it, or escalate it). How can I diagnose the bogus state I have when I first start AnyConnect (is it even related to DNS setup at all) ?

---

Update: I am a simple user (admin of my machine). I am guessing something is bogus, but I'd like to understand the magic behind unplug/replug ethernet cable (what details actually changed: dns, routes ... ?).

---

Update2: Here is my preference page:

[image]

Comment: Are you the router admin? this look like a simple LAN access restriction set inside the connection policy, which block LAN access and force your computer to talk to only corporate ressource

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've toggled "Enable automatic VPN reconnect:

[image: VPN settings page - reconnect feature]

Comment: thanks for the help, but it seems I do not have access to this setting in my version.

Comment: Try activating the two empty checkboxes (top two options) in your settings page?